# Query work in sql server but not in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I want get top 1st row from orders table. The following query works in sql server:

```
select top 1(OrderID)
from dbo.Orders
order by OrderID desc
```

But it does not work in MySql - how should it be written for MySql?

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL use LIMIT

### MySQL

```
select OrderID
from dbo.Orders
order by OrderID desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

### SQL Server

```
select top (1) OrderID
from dbo.Orders
order by OrderID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderID FROM dbo.Orders
ORDER BY OrderID desc 
LIMIT 1;
```